# How to extend the limit of Matchmaker/Relay to avoid server-client disconnection

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

i am facing one issue when using matchmaker concept whereby my client kicked off the server for approximately 1 min.After searching so many links i noticed that this is due to certain bandwidth limit (4KB/S )provided by relay server.Could you please help me how to extend that bandwidth limit to avoid disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Packet headers are included in the bandwidth limit. You might be able to optimize by sending fewer, larger packets.

There's also a few things you can do to compress your data, such as adopting 'smallest three' for quarternions, and representing coarse floats with 8 bit or 16 bit integers. (For example, a float in the range 0-1 can be quantized and represented by `value / ushort.MaxValue`, where `value` is a `ushort`).

If you're still having trouble, you're probably best applying for early access to Photon Thunder, which doesn't have any hard bandwidth limits, as far as I am aware: https://www.photonengine.com/Thunder. Photon Thunder is a drop-in replacement for Unity's matchmaker and relay service; you can continue using the UNet HLAPI.